# Controller POJO vs Method level POJO

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest

What is the best solution for creating POJO, at controller level or method level.
For example I have `EmployeeController` which contains below methods.

```
getAllEmployees()
addEmployee(AddEmployeeRequest employee)
updateEmployee(UpdateEmployeeRequest employee)
removeEmployee(RemoveEmployeeRequest employee)

//Method level classes

public class AddEmployeeRequest
{
    private String name;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String Address;
}

public class UpdateEmployeeRequest
{
    private long id;
    private String Address;
}

public class RemoveEmployeeRequest
{
    private long id;
}
```

or

```
getAllEmployees()
addEmployee(EmployeeRequest employee)
updateEmployee(EmployeeRequest employee)
removeEmployee(EmployeeRequest employee)

//Controller level class
public class EmployeeRequest
{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String Address;
}
```

If I have method level models then do I have to create the respective sevice level DTO models also ?

Comment: I think the best solution for you it's to create a generic POJO.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if you are using spring, it is neccessary to use a single POJO because spring use reflection for accessing the ClassName, DeclaredFields etc. Using multiple POJO will be annoying for Spring.

See here some more details about reflection: https://crunchify.com/create-simple-pojo-and-multiple-java-reflection-examples/